# USB isn't recognized

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers

I've been having this problem with a specific USB of mine.
Once I plug the USB device in a USB port, the device is recognized and comes up in my device manager but shows up transparent in my 'computer' menu.. Each time I want to make it show up I have to uninstall the driver and replug it in so that the driver reinstalls.

Any idea how I might be able to fix this ?

Here are some screenshots for clearance:

first-time plug-in:
[image: first-time plug-in]

removing the driver:
[image: removing the driver]

and after the replug:
[image: after the replug]

Best regards,

Jamey

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you: 1. [start Windows in Safe Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-computer-safe-mode#start-computer-safe-mode=windows-7), 2. [perform a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us), 3. plug the device in a different USB port, or 4. plug the device in a different computer altogether?

Comment: 1. Yes 2. Yes 3. Yes 4. No

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem.  The device doesn't have anything except a USB device driver.  Have you verified your not able to access the drive when its transparent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too faced an issue with my Sandisk USB, but i used to get an error saying, "The media is corrupted, do you want to format it now?" But always failed to format.
The fix for it was found on Sandisk official website. It was a **Sandisk USB Repair Tool**, which fixed all the issues for me and turned back the USB into a healthy state. You may perform a search for this tool. It might rectify your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to my USB once. Turned out that the USB circuitry is damaged due to falling or careless handling. And this has no solution. If every other way fails, then i'd recommend you to was your USB, let it dry and then try inserting it again in your PC. Try it as your last resort.